# Synchronize more than ten javascript functions that gets called at the same time without timeout

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I have got more than 10 functions that are being called at the same time. I want to synchronize them. I want to do it without a timeout, meaning next function gets executed when the one before finishes. Is there a neat way to do it?

Comment: Looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ?

Comment: If your functions are synchronous, call them one after another. If they are asynchronous, use Promises with `await`

Comment: I think you rather want to call them *concurrently*... Synchronization is something different (but related).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `await` on everything, if it returns an actual value it will immediately resolved, otherwise it will wait to be resolved:

```
function fn1() {
  return 10;
}

function fn2() {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000, 20));
}

function fn3() {
   return 30;
}
```

and then:

```
async function main() {
   console.log(await fn1()); // 10
   console.log(await fn2()); // 20, after 1sec
   console.log(await fn3()); // 30
}

main();
```

In that case you can also have an array of functions and loop through it, using always `await` and don't care about the function itself (if it's `async` or what).

P.S.
I just used the timeout for demo purpose, since I didn't have any real async code, I know you don't want to use it; it could be an http request for example (`fetch`), anything is `async` basically.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide your requrement. But you can use [Async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) if that solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
function f1(cb){
  cb();
}

function f2(cb){
  cb();
}

function f3(cb){
  cb();
}

...etc

then...

f1(f2(f3(...etc)));
```

this is not the better way to go... but is good for learning what callback hell is